# Writing Clean JSP code

Tags: jsp, format

One of the problems on my practice exam is:

Writing Clean JSP Code

It  is  very  messy  to  figure  out  what  the  following  jsp  fragment  is  doing. It  uses  the  implicit  variable  out  that  explicitly  writes  in  the  body  of  the  http  response  the  HTML  page  that  is  returned  to  the  browser. 
Rewrite  it  in  the  way  that  a  sane  jsp  programmer  would.

```
<%

 out.write(“<HTML>”);

 out.write(“<HEAD><TITLE>foo</TITLE></HEAD>”);

 out.write(“<BODY> List of Temperatures:”);

 out.write(“<UL><LI>La Jolla:” + weather(“La Jolla”) + “</LI>”); 

 out.write(“<LI>El Cajon:” + weather(“El Cajon”) + “</LI></UL>”);

 out.write(“</BODY></HTML>”);

/%>
```

I'm a little confused. Should the answer just be as following?

```
<html>
<Head><Title>foo</Title></Head>
<Body>
    ....
</Body>
</html>
```

Comment: Account for the `weather(“La Jolla”)`.

Answer (score 1):

JSP technology emphasizes the separation of static content and dynamic content.

It just like a template engine that allows you to define a template which contains the static and dynamic contents . You can use HTML code directly to mark up the static content and use some "placeholders" (i.e tag libraries or by EL expression etc.) to define the  dynamic contents to be inserted into the static content .

In your example , the only dynamic content is the result returned by the function `weather(xxxxx)` . I assume this function can be implemented as the static function which simply accepts a city name and return a string which describing the weather of this city.

[EL expression allow you to define a custom function](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnahq.html#bnaio) . After you implement the `weather(xxxxx)` as the custom EL function , you can call it in the JSP:

```
<html>
<Head><Title>foo</Title></Head>
<Body>
   List of Temperatures:
   <UL>
          <LI>La Jolla:  ${myLibrary:weather("La Jolla")} </LI>
          <LI>El Cajon:  ${myLibrary:weather("El Cajon")} </LI>
   </UL>
</Body>
</html>
```

The JSP should be more clean now as it no longer contains any scriptlet (java code) and all the dynamic contents are encapsulated by the functions in the server-side .

---

Reference

- [Implementing custom EL Functions](http://blog.idleworx.com/2010/04/custom-tags-and-custom-el-functions-in.html)